# Laravel app/public folder on Azure App Service (with nginx)

Tags: php, laravel, azure, nginx

We need to publish a Laravel 8 project on Azure App Services, configured with nginx.
We only have FTPS access and the server runs on nginx. We do not have root or Azure UI access.

We tried to change the public path in server.php to /wwwroot or the relative path to the bootstrap and vendor, as suggested by several posts. Changed webpack mix path etc. But we keep on getting 404 (even though the index.php is there).

How can we configure Laravel to serve the app correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Just to highlight, yes Linux PHP v8 blessed images are defaulted to [nginx/php-fpm](https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/nginx-fpm). So, you will not need .htaccess, however, you may try with rewrite rules to mimic .htaccess.

You can configure using startup command.

[Azure App Service on Linux FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/faq-app-service-linux#what-are-the-expected-values-for-the-startup-file-section-when-i-configure-the-runtime-stack-)

Just to confirm, does it work locally fine as expected? You try these to isolate the issue further.

•   Access the log stream.

•   Test the app locally in production mode. App Service runs your app in production mode, so you need to make sure that your project works as expected in production mode locally.

For example:

o   Depending on your composer.json, different packages may be installed for production mode (require vs. require-dev).

o   Certain web frameworks may deploy static files differently in production mode.

o   Certain web frameworks may use custom startup scripts when running in production mode.

•   Run your app in App Service in debug mode. In Laravel, you can configure your app to **output debug messages in production** by setting the `APP_DEBUG app setting to true`.

If your requirement fits, you may deploy your Laravel application with a custom Docker image instead.